# Printing of PDF document in C# that contains images generated from Byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, pdf, printing

I have two images on my web page that I have created using the `iTextSharp Image` function that converts the image byte data in the database to images. Now I want to convert both images into a single PDF and then print the PDF. The converting of the PDF is working but the print dialog box does not open. My code is as below. Here `image1` and `image2` are the `asp:Images` in the web page where the two images are displayed.

```
protected void button_print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] img1 = null;
        byte[] img2 = null;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("select Image1, Image2 from Images where ID=@id", con);
            select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ViewState["ImageID"].ToString());
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            using (SqlDataReader da = select.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (da.Read())
                {
                    img1 = (byte[])da["Image1"];
                    img2 = (byte[])da["Image2"];
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // throws exception
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open || con.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img1, 0, img1.Length);
        image2.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img2, 0, img2.Length);
        iTextSharp.text.Image imageOne = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(CreateThumbnail(img1));
        iTextSharp.text.Image imageTwo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(CreateThumbnail(img2));
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(imageOne);
            Paragraph line = new Paragraph("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            line.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            document.Add(line);
            document.Add(imageTwo);
            document.Close();
            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        // CODE FOR PRINTING THE PDF DOCUMENT
    }
    catch
    {
        // throws exception
    }
}
```

I am not sure what functions to use for opening the print dialog boxes. I tried a few such as `PrintDialog` but not sure how it works. Can someone suggest me a better way to print the PDF document that works in all web browsers and all printers? If possible with the code for printing the PDF document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a web application it is running in a web browser. You can't instruct a web browser to print a PDF object without downloading it first. Even after downloading the PDF document you can't have the web application print the PDF automatically after download.

A better approach for web is to convert the PDF to HTML or even better make sure the document and it's content is a webpage by itself. You can have the webbrowser show the print dialog by running one line of javascript. If you want to have this automatically you can put it in the page load event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  window.print();
});
```

Comment: But how does it work in my case? I don't have the image saved on the computer. The images are on the web page and it should automatically go to the printer when I click on a button. That's why I'm creating the PDF myself using the images on the webpage.

Comment: You said the converting of the PDF was working so I assumed the images are in. So your question is not so much how to print but how to get those images in a PDF correct?

Comment: No no. Converting of the images to PDF is working. But after converting to PDF, it should automatically open in print dialog without saving the PDF in the computer

Comment: The converted PDF is stored in this variable `Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);`. How can i send this to print dialog directly in C# code?

Comment: The application that you are building, is it a webapplication or a desktop application? If it is desktop I suggest to store the PDF in the temp directory and print it from there with the code in the answer. Either delete it after or have the OS take care of cleaning that up.

Comment: Web application. `.aspx` pages. I have a button in the web page that executes this function. On button click, it will fetch the byte data (binary data stored in database) of the images from database and then converts them to image objects using `iTextSharp`. These image objects are then put inside a PDF document using the `MemoryStream` and `PdfWriter`. Finally, i have a PDF document object. Now I want to print this PDF document using this PDF document object.

Comment: If it's a webapplication it doesnt make sense to generate a PDF. You can't have a webbrowser print a PDF that is not in some way downloaded first.  What you can do is generate a webpage and have JavaScript do the printing for you. I wil update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153440/discussion-between-bert-sinnema-and-mano-prathibhan-c).